# Curious if angularJs has better method to calculate number of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to check if any checkbox is checked. so i am doing it like

```
self.isButtonEnabled = function() {
  var selectLineCheckboxs = document.getElementsByClassName('selectLineRadioInput'), 
  i = 0, checkboxLength = selectLineCheckboxs.length - 1;

  for (i = 0; i <= checkboxLength; i++) {
    if (selectLineCheckboxs[i].checked) {
      self.selectLineChecked = true;
      break;
    } else {
      self.selectLineChecked = false;
    }
  }
  return self.selectLineChecked;
};
```

in return i get true if any checkbox is checked.

so quite simple,

Now here i am looking if we can do the same with angularJs with any better approach and i do not want to use watch() function in angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help with your some code to convert it to look like in Angular way.

1. use `angular.element` (provided by [**jQLite**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to get element) as instead of `document.getElementsByClassName`
2. You could use `$filter` while checking attribute is checked or not

**CODE**

```
self.isButtonEnabled = function() {
    var selectLineCheckboxs = angular.element('.selectLineRadioInput');
    var checkedValues = $filter('filter')(selectLineCheckboxs, { 'checked': true }); //do filtering and contains check value
    self.selectLineChecked = checkedValues.length > 0 ? true : false;
    return self.selectLineChecked;
};
```

**Note:** You should add `$filter` dependency on your controller before using `$filter`

**Update**

I'd suggest you to create your own custom filter that could be usable in multiple purposes, or dynamically check property value is true or not. I know your code is as same as you ask in answer, but I putted some of your code as reusable component, which can dynamically work for any property value to check is true or not.

**Filter**

```
.filter('isPropertyTrue', function () {
    return function (elements, property) {
        var returnArray = [];
        angular.forEach(elements, function (val, index) {
            if (val[property]) returnArray.push(val)
        });
        return returnArray;
    }
});
```

**Code**

```
$scope.isButtonEnabled = function () {
    var selectLineCheckboxs = document.getElementsByClassName('selectLineRadioInput');
    var checkedValues = $filter('isPropertyTrue')(selectLineCheckboxs, 'checked');
    self.selectLineChecked = checkedValues.length > 0 ? true : false;
    return self.selectLineChecked;
};
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h91avkn8/2/)**
Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: @mayank does it helpful to you?

Comment: This line has issue $filter('filter')(selectLineCheckboxs, { 'checked': true }); this returns all checkbox but not all those checked !!

Comment: @downvoter could I know the reason behind down vote?

Answer (score 0):

i have been using it this way with ng-bind variable in scope `$scope.Items` .and the binded variable can be used to see what all items are checked.

```
 angular.forEach($scope.Items,function(key,value)
                  {          
                                if(key.Selected)
                                {
                                    counter++;
                                }
                     });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/h91avkn8/1/) is a JSFiddle to illustrate the same

Comment: Number of checkbox i am getting from API which is dynamic.so i cant set $scope.Items name obj

Comment: if you can use jQuery may be this would be helpful 
`$('form input[type=checkbox]:checked').size()`

Comment: I cant use jquery only javascript only